# In Imageshack's API, what does the public/private option actually mean?

Tags: api, web-applications, imageshack

In Imageshack's API, what does the public/private option actually mean? Is there some kind of directory that the image will appear in if it is designated as public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's public, it's [searchable](http://img55.imageshack.us/new_search.php?s=1&q=stack+overflow)